# Delphi- downloading files from the web with sockets

Tags: delphi, http, sockets

I have tried Synapse, Indy and ICS and I am not satisfied with them. I want to download multiple files in multiple parts at the same time, support resuming, gzip-encoded files, cookies, logging to websites using POST and so on. So I think I will just write in with sockets.
But I see there is a plenty of sockets available in Delphi: TTcpClient, TRawSocket, TCGIRequest, TClientSocket and so on. They are all badly documented- very hard to find usage examples. I tried using TTcpClient but sometimes the program freezes and then hits a timeout and I have no idea why. Looks like a problem while waiting for responses. This is surely not a server problem because I test on localhost.
What is the best socket to use to work with HTTP protocol? Something easy to use?

I want to use in both Delphi 7 and XE2. I don't want to use anything WinAPI like, so I don't have to deal with PChars and other non-Delphi things.

I am thinking of something like, either:

1) Does exactly what I want- downloads multiple pieces with progressbars of many files at the same file

OR

2) Something like telnet- so I just write HTTP commands as strings and I get arrays of bytes in return which I can either transform into strings or save into tstreams.

Comment: Try WinInet.  It's fully supported by Delphi; it doesn't require any add-ons.  It might be ideal for your purposes: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/wininet.htm

Comment: What's wrong with Indy ? Or asynchronous ICS (maybe better suited for parallel file downloading) ?

Comment: Even further, what version of Delphi are you using? `TClientSocket` is obsolete now and even in older versions of Delphi where it *was* supported, it's still highly advised not to even think about using them. Delphi version is important for a question like this. Not to mention this is not a fit question for StackOverflow in the first place.

Comment: "What should I use" is one bad question for S/O, "Something easy to use" is even worse, it's subjective. Both combined together is a terrible question here.

Comment: @paulsm4 I edited my question- I don't want to use WinAPI, I prefer standard Delphi "things".

Comment: @JerryDodge I know this is not the best question I could ask, sorry. I want something to "emulate" Telnet- I send commands as strings, I get bytes in return.

Comment: @TLama I put 10 Indy TIdHTTP components on form and tried downloading with them but it was terribly slow. I could not find a way to easily resume downloads, download multiple parts.

Comment: @Tom: TIdHTTP supports everything you are asking for, you just have to know how to use it.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot comment on the other libraries, but Indy supports everything you are asking for.

The `TIdHTTP` component can download files using byte ranges, if the server supports it.  You can use the `TIdHTTP.Head()` method to check if the server return a `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header for a given URL.  If it does, then you can set the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentRangeStart` and `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentRangeEnd` properties to the desired byte offets as needed when downloading the data from that URL.  To download multiple parts of a resource at the same time, simply run multiple threads, each with its own `TIdHTTP` component, in parallel.  You will have to then either download multiple pieces to separate temp files and then merged them together into the final file when finished, or else create a single pre-sized file and then open multiple `TFileStream` objects to it at the desired starting offsets for `TIdHTTP` to write to.

`TIdHTTP` supports cookies.  You can either assign a `TIdCookieManager` component to the `TIdHTTP.CookieManager` property, or you can leave it unassigned and `TIdHTTP` will create a `TIdCookieManager` object internally.  Either way, also set the `TIdHTTP.AllowCookies` property to True.

Website login be accomplished one of two different ways, depending on whether the server uses HTTP-based authentication or WebForm-based authentication:

1. For HTTP authentication, add desired `IdAuthentication...` units to your `uses` clause, like `IdAuthentacationDigest` and `IdAuthenticationNTLM`, or the `IdAllAuthentications` unt, to register individual authentication classes with `TIdHTTP`, and then set the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserName` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` properties as needed.  If the WebServer asks for authentication during a request, `TIdHTTP` will pick the appropriate class and use it to login with the specified credentials.  If the server rejects the credentials, the `TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization` event will be fired to give you a chance to change the credentials and try again.
2. For WebForm authentication, there is a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` class that can be passed to the `TIdHTTP.Post()` method for posting a `multipart/form-data` formatted POST request.

`TIdHTTP` in Indy 10 supports gzip-files and deflate-compressed files (`TIdHTTP` in Iny 9 and earlier does not support compression).  You can assign a `TIdZLibCompressorBase`-derived component, such as `TIdCompressorZLib`, to the `TIdHTTP.Compressor` property, and `TIdHTTP` will handle all of the details for you, including sending an appropriate `Accept-Encoding` request header, and checking the server's `Transfer-Encoding` response header.

`TIdHTTP` has `OnWorkBegin`, `OnWork`, and `OnWorkEnd` events that can be used for progress bar and such.  The `OnWorkBegin` event has an `AWorkCountMax` parameter that specifies the total number of bytes being transferred if known, otherwise it will be 0 (HTTP responses that use a `Content-Length` header will set the `AWorkCountMax` accordingly, but HTTP responses that use a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header will not).  The `OnWork` event has an `AWorkCount` parameter that specifies how many bytes have been transferred so far, regardless of the `AWorkCounMax` value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your components. Since I have no other replies and they closed my question I will give Indy another try :)